# Inherited component fails to update property in base component

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have an Angular component inheriting a base component.

```
@Component({
selector: "my-baseclass-component",

template: `
  <div style="border:1px solid red;padding:10px">
   counter value (check console to see it gets incremented) : {{ counter }}
  <ng-content select="[body]"></ng-content>
  <br />
</div>
`
 })
 export class BaseClassComponent {
 public counter = 0;
 constructor() {}
 }
```

I just want to increment a counter in the base component from the inherited component when clicking on a button.

```
@Component({
selector: 'my-inherited-component',
template: `<my-baseclass-component #myBaseclass>
 <div style="border:1px solid black" body>Inherited Component Content
<button (click)="click()">toggle</button>
 </div>
  </my-baseclass-component>`
})
 export class InheritedComponent extends BaseClassComponent {  

  click(){
    this.counter++;
    console.log('clicked:' + this.counter);
  }
}
```

The counter variable is displayed in the base component template using the curly brackets notation `{{counter}}` but it is never refreshed although the value itself is incremented correctly.

I have reproduced the issue in a stackblitz :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sssxvt?file=src/app/baseclass.component.ts

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put `<app-some-comp></app-some-comp>` in template you tell Angular to instantiate **a new isolated instance** of `AppSomeComponent`.

In your example

```
@Component({
  ...
  template: `
       <my-baseclass-component #myBaseclass>
           ....
      </my-baseclass-component>`
})
export class InheritedComponent extends BaseClassComponent {}
```

you created `InheritedComponent` component(which is derived from `BaseClassComponent` class) and **a new separated instance** of `<my-baseclass-component`.

If you want the `counter` to be reflected in inner `<my-baseclass-component` component you should update it itself.

There are several options:

- Update it manually https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gr3ws3?file=src%2Fapp%2Finherited.component.ts:

  ```
  (click)="click(); myBaseclass.counter = counter"
  ```
- Use property binding https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fhj7n7?file=src%2Fapp%2Finherited.component.ts

  ```
  export class BaseClassComponent {
    @Input() counter = 0;


  <my-baseclass-component [counter]="counter">
  ```

Comment: Thank you @yurzui for the clear explanations; That makes perfect sense now. Well-deserved bounty :) (I have to wait 20 hours before I can grant it to you but I'll do it)